# What component do I need to add to 24V sensor to conver to discrete high/low output for Shelly switch

Tags: mosfet, resistors, sensor

I'm working on a simple smart home project where I've installed some 24V LED strips inside a pantry cabinet.

I'm using an infrared door control switch to detect when the door opens and closes and turn of the LED strip accordingly.
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003631050899.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.27.1f401802bC7Dz2

I also have a Tuya Smart Home dimmer connected to control the lighting and dim the LED strip at night.

The 24V power supply is connected to the smart dimmer, the door sensor, and the LED strips.

[image]

While this was all working, I wasn't too happy with the dimming performance of the Tuya dimmer so I've decided to use a Shelly RGBW dimmer instead which provides much better low dimming performance (via PWM). Unfortunately, the door sensor doesn't play nicely with the Shelly device and causes the lights to flicker at low dim levels. I think this might be due to the sensor having some additional electronics which also dims the lights to off when the door closes.

Instead of wiring the door sensor inline, I'm thinking of using it as a switch to control the Shelly. This however doesn't appear to work as the output from the sensor still provides a current instead of a hard 0 when the door is closed.

[image]

I need to convert the high/low output to a more discrete output. I'd rather not use a relay to keep things quiet. Do I need some resisters, transistors, MOSFETs? Alternatively, if anyone has any suggestions on stopping the flickering, then maybe that might be simpler.

I measure about 23V on the output of the sensor when the door is open and it floats around 5V when closed. I'm not entirely sure about the Shelly input requirements. I've previously used a simple push button switch or a reed switch with a similar Shelly device and they seem to work.

I haven't been able to find much info on the door sensor. The sensor has a label with LP-5026M. For the [ShellyRGBW device](https://kb.shelly.cloud/knowledge-base/shelly-rgbw2), the info doesn't mention specifics on the switch, but the wiring diagram shows a very simple switch in operation.
[image]

The LED strips are [BTF-Lighting 24V COB](https://www.btf-lighting.com/collections/all-products/products/fcob-cct-ic-led-light-strip-addressable-576-leds-2700k-to-6500k-10mm-dc24v-flexible-high-density-cob-ra90)

Comment: Do you have schematics and data sheets for the products you have listed?

Comment: _"This however doesn't appear to work as the output from the sensor still provides a current instead of a hard 0 when the door is closed."_ Isn't that behavior software controlled?

Comment: I haven't been able to find much info on the door sensor. The sensor has a label with LP-5026M. 

For the ShellyRGBW device, the info is available here https://kb.shelly.cloud/knowledge-base/shelly-rgbw2. 

The LED strips are BTF-Lighting 24V COB https://www.btf-lighting.com/collections/all-products/products/fcob-cct-ic-led-light-strip-addressable-576-leds-2700k-to-6500k-10mm-dc24v-flexible-high-density-cob-ra90

Comment: do you have a multimeter? What's the output of the door sensor? What does the Shelly require on its input to switch? Once we know those, we can help you choose and configure some parts to interface the two.

Comment: About 23V when the door is open and floats around 0V when closed. I'll need to measure the current and report back. I'm not entirely sure about the Shelly input requirements. I've previously used a simple push button switch or a reed switch with a similar Shelly device and they seem to work.

Comment: @Mkov Please edit your question to add the additional information and links.